# sslv3 handshake failure (0x14077410) connecting from MarkLogic Server

Tags: openssl, marklogic, sslv3

I'm using MarkLogic 8 and trying to do a POST request to a server.  I'm able to connect via curl or using POSTMan, however, its failing with Markloigc.  A similar post suggested that its an issue with SNI as Markloigc uses OpenSSL.  I have tried to put the  option in the post request, however, I'm still getting the same error.  Any insights to resolving this issue?  See code snippet below:

```
xdmp:http-post($post_url,
                        <options xmlns="xdmp:http">
                         <data>{xdmp:quote($custom_json)}</data>                              
                         <headers>
                           <content-type>application/json</content-type>
                           <Host>{$host}</Host>
                         </headers>
                         <allow-sslv3>true</allow-sslv3>
                       </options>
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you're sending any credentials. Try something like this:

```
xdmp:http-post(
    $post_url,
    <options xmlns="xdmp:http">
        <data>{xdmp:quote($custom_json)}</data>                              
        <headers>
            <content-type>application/json</content-type>
            <Host>{$host}</Host>
        </headers>
        <allow-sslv3>true</allow-sslv3>
        <authentication method="digest">
            <username>myUsername</username>
            <password>myPassword</password>
        </authentication>
    </options>
)
```

Comment: The Post url contains a token which replaces the authentication.  I have tried the following with OpenSSL sclient and was able to connect when I added the -servername parameter.  For Example: 
I CANNOT connect when I try:
openssl s_client -connect <ip>:443

I CAN connect when i try:
openssl s_client -servername <host.org> -connect <ip>:443

Question is how do I pass the -servername parameter in MarkLogic xdmp:http-post url?

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this thread, I have tested the same code in MarkLogic 9 and it is working.  I'm not sure if this is a combination of Marklogic 8 and the OpenSSL library its using.